# How to refactor a controller that handles two variants of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, controller

I have a controller `ads_controller.rb` which handles all ads on our platfrom.
This controller also handles a subset of the original `ad.rb`model, which is called `house_ad`.
*(`house_ad` is not a model. House ads are ads with a specific property.)*

At many places in the view code there are differences between the things that are shown for `ads` and `house_ads` (handled with an instance variable `@is_house_ad`). In order to have cleaner code we want to remove this extra handling of `house_ads` within the `ads_controller.rb` and move the behaviour to a `house_ads_controller.rb`.

Unfortunately I am not very familiar with that kind of problem so I am searching for advice how to approach it.

**Note**:

My first idea was to inherit `house_ads_controller.rb` from `ads_controller.rb` and then override the functions that differentiate between regular ads and house ads.

It turned out that this is true for most of the existing functions and that this solution would therefore produce a lot of duplicate code which would ultimately make maintenance harder.

Q: **What would be the best way to remove these many occurrences of variation handling without producing lots of duplicate code?**

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have lots of code in your controllers, which in general is [not particularly idiomatic for Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550376/rails-skinny-controller-vs-fat-model-or-should-i-make-my-controller-anorexic). Ideally start by refactoring this code into your `ad` and `house_ad` models, making sure that you obey inheritance properly and try not to duplicate any code. If you need, you should make use of Mixins - they might help.

Then, your controller should work for both `ad` and `house_ad`, and at most you might need some tweaking on your display logic, but it should be minimal if you get your models design correctly.

Lastly, you could refactor `@is_house_ad` out and instead use `model.is_a?` Model in your view logic.

Answer (score 1):

As I read it, the code duplication is not in your controller but in your views. If that is the case there are some alternatives:

I will create a small example, to make things clearer. E.g. suppose your code contains something like this

```
<% if @ad.is_house_ad? %>
  <%= @ad.house_ad_title %>
<% else %>
  <%= @ad.title %>
<% end %>
```

(and I presume it will contain a ton of those ;)

#### Move code to your `AdsHelper`

In your view write:

```
<%= get_title(@ad) %>
```

In your `AdsHelper` you write

```
def get_title(ad)
  ad.is_house_ad? ? ad.house_ad_title : ad.title
end
```

This will clear up the view, and put all code nicely in one place. But, as you can tell: it is not object-oriented.

#### Move more code to your model

Since your model knows how it should be interpreted, this seems a logical place. But you might be pulling view-code into your model.

In your model

```
def show_title
  ad.is_house_ad? ? ad.house_ad_title : ad.title
end
```

In your view:

```
<%= ad.show_title %>
```

#### Use different partials

This is a very simple solution, and cleanly splits the views.

So in your view, write:

```
<% if @ad.is_house_ad? %>
  <%= render :partial => 'house_ad' %>
<% else %>
  <%= render :partial => 'ad' %>
<% end %>
```

Then, in the partial `_ad.html.erb`:

```
<%= @ad.title %>
```

And in the partial `_house_ad.html.erb`:

```
<%= @ad.ad_house_title %>
```

I think this is best combined by using one of both previous solutions. But maybe using this, may alleviate the need for one of the previous, depends on the complexity of your code and view.

#### Use presenters

Instead of adding view-code to your model, you create a presenter. In this case you could even create two presenters: a `AdPresenter` and a `HouseAdPresenter`. It is this object that is instantiated in the controller, based on the model. And it is this object that is then handed to the view. The presenter will hide all differences, and if you ask the title it will just present the correct one.

Using presenter is a well-known paradigm, and there was a [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/286-draper?view=asciicast) about it recently.

#### Use STI

Maybe the cleanest solution, but the most work, is to use Single Table Inheritance. This means you have one database-table, with a `Type`, which could contain two models (sounds recognizable?). This would mean you would have two models `Ad` and `HouseAd`, who both inherit from a base-class. This could also mean two controllers, but in your case I do not think the duplication is in the controller.

Depending on your code/view, I think the easiest way to start is to first introduce the partials, or start moving code to the helpers or models.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Given what we know from the question, I especially like your last two suggestions: presenters and STI.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer without any concrete example(s).

If it's "little chunks" of different functionality throughout the mainline code, those parts can be refactored into class-specific methods.

For example, if the more-specialized class method is exactly the same as the superclass except for a chunk of code in the middle, the superclass would define an extension point method and keep it empty in itself, and the subclass would override.

If it's initialization-like code it can often be moved into a `before` filter (or `after` if it's code towards the end).

Rails tends towards fat models, though, and skinny controllers. (Sometimes this is just trading one problem for another, but that's a different discussion.) See if functionality specifically around the model can be moved into the model itself.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not give any examples about what the differences are, I can't give very detailed advice. But what you are looking for in general are design patterns, of which several address problems like you describe them, for example the Decorator pattern.

Maybe you should have a look at  "Design Patterns in Ruby" by Russ Olsen (or any similar book, but I would recommend this one). I'm sure that you will find several possible solutions how to change either your controller or the models to clean up your code without building complicated inheritances.