# Rails: how to handle after_create: create_subscription?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is the case:

When user create topic, they can choose whether `subscribe` to this topic or not.
If the subscribe, then when other user reply to their topic, they would receive notifications.

I think there are 2 ways to do it.

1. `after_create` in Model `topic.rb`

When user decide not subscribe to their topic, we escape this method.

2. `create` in Controller `TopicsController`

something like `if params[‘subscribe’]` from the form user submitted.

I think `after_create` feels more structural, but putting it in model seems too deep.

What would be a good way of handling this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although generally "fat model, skinny controller" is a good rule of thumb, it's really just there for inexperienced developers who don't push enough down to the model.

The real rule should be "the code should sit where the code belongs".  If the subscription is dependent on user input then it doesn't necessarily belong in the Topic model.

Sometimes it makes sense to package processes into a `service object` that your controller can call. It will accept your input, do some actions including updating one or more models as appropriate, and return a result.

https://netguru.co/blog/service-objects-in-rails-will-help

Answer (score 0):

I think that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2550556/564139) can help you

> Controllers are best at parsing inputs, calling the appropriate models, and then formatting the outputs.

And generally speaking, you may want to check out the subject of "Fat model, skinny controller".